# Number of Solutions to the given Expression

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity, combinations, linear-algebra

I have been solving a problem and have been stuck on for a long time now :

**Problem Statement :**

We have to solve multiple queries for this problem.

For Each query,
we are given two integers n,k.

n denotes the total number of integer variables (x1,x2,...xn).

Let X be the total number of possible solutions for the below expression,

x1 + x2+ x3 + ... + xn = k,

such that **0 <= xi < i**  , i.e., x1<1, x2<2, x3<3 .... xn<n.

We need to report whether X is **ODD** or **EVEN**.

Constraints : 1 <= k <= n <= 1e10.

**My Approach**:

The best possible solution I am able to come up with is of the order O(N*K) with the help of dynamic programming.

Any sort of leads will be helpful. Thanks!

**Update:** 
Sample Case :

We have 4 queries : (3,0), (3,1), (3,2), (3,3)

Here in all queries n = 3

[ REMEMBER QUERIES CAN HAVE DIFFERENT N ]

```
     for k=0 : Total cases = 1 (0,0,0) => so Result ODD

     for k=1 : Total cases = 2 (0,0,1), (0,1,0) => Result EVEN
```

[**NOTE** : Here (1,0,0) won't be counted as according                        to constraints, x1<1, x2<2, x3<3]

```
     for k=2 : Total cases = 2 (0,1,1), (0,0,2) => Result EVEN

     for k=3 : Total cases = 1 (0,1,2) => Result ODD
```

Comment: Please give pairs of sample input and correct output examples. I get the impression that programming is the wrong approach and a direct calculcation O(1) is the path to go. The examples should help me to understand better.

Comment: Are the `x` integers? That seem to have an influence on the total number of solutions, though probably not on the even/odd required answer.

Comment: Please [edit] to add information to the question.

Comment: @Yunnosch Yes the x are integers. I updated the blog.

Comment: If you mistake this for a blog you should urgently take the [tour].

Comment: @Yunnosch Thanks for the tour, Do you have anything in mind regarding the approach to the problem?

Comment: Nothing concrete. But my gut feeling did not change from my first comment.

Comment: Still some things are unclear. I recommend to give more explanation details on why the desired outputs are as shown. What is n in each case? Why not more? If caseses are `(0,0,1), (0,1,0)`  why not `(1,0,0)`? (I think I know, but explaining might get people faster into the mind set for this question.)

Comment: The more you explain your thoughts the better the chances for help are. Never mind thoughts being "too obvious". Explain all you thought. Not least because this kind of rubber ducking might lead you yourself to the solution. Then you could make your own appreciated answer here.

Comment: @Yunnosch, For a given (n,k) n-> represents the total number of variables (x1,x2,...xn) whose sum should be equal to k. 

Regarding your doubt that why can't we take (1,0,0), I already mentioned in problem statement that 0<= xi < i, i.e., x1<1, x2<2, x3<3 and so on

Comment: Please [edit] to add information to the question.

Comment: I get the impression that calculating would not be hard if you at first ignore the `k <= n` requirement. Then check what changes are caused by that requirement.

Comment: @Yunnosch I updated the question to make it as understanding as I can.  If you come up with anything please let me know. One thing that I observed is , for query (i,j) lets denote DP[i][j] = 1, if the result is odd else DP[i][j] = 0, if the result is even, For j<i, DP[i][j] = DP[i-1][j] ^ DP[i][j-1], where ^ denotes XOR operator. Could this be used somehow to reduce to constant time?

Comment: @Yunnosch I came up with an idea. For a query (n,k) we basically need to find the parity of the coefficient of x^k in (1+x)(1+x+x^2)....(1+x+x^2...+x^n). Are you aware about any fast way to find the parity of the coefficient?

Comment: Parity is modulo 2, isn't it?

Comment: @Yunnosch yes, we need to report 0 or 1

Comment: This is more of a math problem than it is a programming problem. Do a Google search for "constrained stars and bars", that should point you in the right direction on how to calculate this.